# Why are my rigid body objects sometimes passing through this surface?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

I am designing a dice rolling device that holds three dice in a dome shaped object, but having issues with the dice colliding with the dome. All three dice have the same rigid body settings, however one completely ignores the dome object, the other two collide with the initial movement but then bounce off the first collision and fall out. I was wondering if someone could help me with keeping the three dice within the dome and the base of the dome (which is a different object)

Blend file below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: After setting the dome to "Convex Hull" and increasing its mass (in blender, the mass also controls how strong the object is), I managed to keep the other two dice inside. Couldn't figure out why the third one just flies away though.

Comment: Thank you Eric I appreciate it!